# Updating HTML table through JSTL and SQL

Tags: sql, jsp, jstl

I have a HTML table which initially displays all records in the DB. I have just added a JQuery Datepicker component, and now I want to be able to retrieve records based on date. I have no problem extracting the date from the Datepicker component, but I do have a problem updating the existing HTML table. My code is pretty standard.

```
<sql:query var="retrieveSecurity" dataSource="jdbc/SecurityApp">SELECT * FROM security</sql:query>

<tbody>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${retrieveSecurity.rows}">
<tr>
<td>${row.security_id}</td>
<td>${row.description}</td>
<td class="center">${row.bid_price}</td>
<td class="center">${row.bid_percent_change}</td>
<td>${row.comment}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

What I basically want to do is to have another SQL query, something like this...

```
<sql:query var="retrieveSecurity" dataSource="jdbc/SecurityApp">SELECT * FROM security where trade_date = "MYVALUE"
</sql:query>
```

I then want to be able to update the the tbody tag to point to this new SQL query, and call it instead. The columns won't change, so it should be the same table, just with filtered data. Not sure if what I am asking is the easiest/best solution, just looking for something that will work quickly for a prototype.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You need to fill that table using `ajax`

Comment: How you are sending the second request with selected date? Either by submitting the page or tried any [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) solutions?

Comment: I listen to the onSelect() function on the Datepicker component which then queries the DB successful. I have the correct data, I just need to update the the table at this point.

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving some data returned by your (date picker) event? If so post that datepicker code and relative events.